# Excel If Else Formula comparing string values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First I'm no Excel formula guru..

I want to write a formula that is comparing 4 possible string values

such as:  Up, Down, Left, Right

pseudocode would be say:

```
if a1="Up" and a2="Down" then 1.1
else if a1="Left" and a2="Right" then 1.1
else if a1="Left" and a2="Down" then .95
else if a1 = a2 then 1
```

I'd cover all the permutations..

Comment: answer:  =IF(R25=R26,1,IF(AND(R25="Up",R26="Down"),1.1,IF(AND(R25="Down",R26="Up"),1.1,IF(AND(R25="Left",R26="Right"),1.1,IF(AND(R25="Right",R26="Left"),1.1,0.95)))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I view it as 6 nested if tests

- 4 items to test/compare
- 6 tests emerge
- 1x2,1x3,1x4,2x3,2x4,3x4

`=IF(1=2,do this,if(1=3,do this,if(1=4,do this,if(2=3,do this,if(2=4,do this,if(3=4,do this,value if every test fails))))))`

I *THINK* Excel has a limit of 7 nested if formulas or perhaps even formulas in general.

Comment: gone it thanks.. I thought I'd have to go through all permutations but I saw that value if everything fails.. since after 5 conditions I know what the result must be I didn't max out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this?

```
=IF("Test1"="","Equal1
","")&IF("Test2"="","Equal2
","")&IF("Test3"="","Equal3
","")&IF("Test4"="","Equal4
","")
```

Borrowed from basically the same question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/379681/258902).

Comment: don't think so.. or maybe I'm not coding test correctly.  Test needs to be a test on two conditions.. ie. a1="up" & a2="down".

Comment: Try my answer but replace my basic equal test "1=2" with `AND(a1="up",a2="down")`